# Передача чувствительных данных в запросе

Tags: запрос, безопасность, backend

Нужно пользователю в email сообщении отдать ссылку страницу восстановления аккаунта, нужно передать не просто ссылку на эндпоинт, но и чтобы в ссылке содержался и сам токен восстановления.

И думал передавать эту ссылку как параметр запроса:

```
message = EmailMessage.RecoveryAccountBody + $"{_fileManager.GetReactAppUrl(App.REACT_LAUNCH_JSON_PATH, true)}/auth/recovery?token={token}"
```

Но параметры запроса сохраняются в истории браузера, а мне хотелось бы этого избежать.

Единственный вариант который я вижу это в сообщении отдавать чистый токен, и чтобы пользователь сам вводил этот токен в форму, и потом данные с формы (токен) передавать в теле запроса, но это не самый удобный вариант.

Есть ли еще какие-то варианты ?

Comment: А чем вам не угодил токен в истории? Все так делают и никто не парится

Comment: @andreymal Не хочу даже немного рисковать, хоть время жизни у токена короткое

Comment: Рисковать чем? О чём речь?

Comment: @andreymal С помощью этого токена можно восстановить аккаунт, если проще восстановить пароль от аккаунта, без ввода каких-либо доп данных.

Comment: @air2921 ну можно, в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Всего-то и нужно, чтобы токен был одноразовый и тогда история адресной строки не будет проблемой. И никаких рисков нет.

Comment: Да даже если не одноразовый, я всё равно не вижу проблемы, просто не надо показывать историю браузера кому попало

Comment: @andreymal, не-не. токен для восстановления пароля должен быть одноразовый. И лучшая схема - зашел и тебя тут же  заставили изменить пароль (ни в кем случае не высылать его открытым текстом по почте)

Comment: Токен одноразовый, и имеет короткое время жизни. Но я думаю над возможной, хоть и маловероятной ситуацией: Юзер создал токен восстановления, перешел по ссылке, и немного отложил процесс восстановления аккаунта, и допустим ситуацию что у юзера на пк может быть какое-то вредоносное ПО, которое считывает историю браузера (Которую похитить не проблема), и в истории будет токен, в таком случае токен утек в чужие руки)) )

Comment: @Jour во первых речь не об активации, а о восстановлении доступа (т.е. ситуация "забыл пароль"). Во вторых даже если и активация - тоже одноразовое действие - отработал токен - в мусорку его.

Comment: @SeVlad с одноразовостью активации у меня была проблема: пользователи тыкали ссылку двойным кликом, а потом прибегли ко мне жаловаться, что сайт отвечает ошибкой, пришлось сделать его многоразовым

Comment: @air2921 как только юзер перешел по ссылке - всё, токен протух. Вот так должны работать одноразовые токен, А на открывшейся странице (например с формой ввода нового пароля) юзер может висеть сколь угодно долго. Но актуальность - до её закрытия (куки).

Comment: @andreymal да, есть такая проблема, но тут в чём косяк - токен протухает раньше, чем догрузилась страница. На крайняк можно сделать задержку протухания на пару сек.

Comment: @SeVlad В таком случае, да, я путаю понятия токен не одноразовый. Но все равно если юзер провисит на ссылку больше 30 минут, и отправит запрос на восстановление через 35 минут, сервер ответит тем что токен протух, и нужен новый.

Comment: Потер свои сообщения... что за флуд вы тут развели) одноразовый/ограниченный токен решает проблему без какой-либо потери безопасности. досвидания.

Comment: @air2921, ну это может быть нормально. Хотя я бы не ограничивал время сколько держать страницу открытой) Но можешь там обратный таймер повесить. чтобы юзер сопли не жевал и понимал..

Comment: Все успокоились, прекрасно) еще как вариант вшить в хеш что-то вроде айпи (мак, ОС).. например + еще какие-то данные) тогда подменить запрос другим пользователем будет оооочень сложно) тоесть ваш первоначальный ключ будет не просто хешем циферок, а набор из данных юзера пропатченные спец кличем) после чего получаем ключ + проверяем его на подлинность с помощью дополнительных махинаций)